# Reduce lateral movement for polycarbonate roof over existing deck?

Tags: decking, pergola

[image]So we are in the process of adding a polycarbonate roof (suntuf) over our existing deck. It's an A-frame roof with different pitches on each side (because I tried where I could to tie my posts into the existing deck footings.

The peak of the roof is about 10.5' and the sides are 8', one run is About 13.5' and the other run in 8.5'. The middle posts are 4x6 with dual 2x12s notched into it on each side leaving 2.5" in the middle. The sides are 4x4 posts with a single 2x12 to rest the rafters on. I birdsmouthed the rafters on both sides and sat them directly on the 2x12s and used structural screws to tie them in, along with hurricane ties.

The 4x6 closest to the house, it tied directly into the framing of the house, so the top is very solid, no lateral movement.

However the 4x6 further out has some lateral play if I go up on the ladder and push it back and forth. It's not a lot I'm not exactly concerned about it causing any issues since at human height it is very solid so I wouldn't worry about someone pushing it.

However with that said, it does get fairly windy and I would like to get it as secure as possible. I know I need to add some triangles somewhere but I'm not sure where, I also considered possibly trying to use tension wire and make a 'X' shape under the rafters.

In the picture, the green box is attached to the house, the blue boxes are solid and attached to the original decking 4x4 in concrete. The yellow box is where I can still get a bit of play on it.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.